# Python is not reporting any errors and I cannot for the life of me figure out where I am going wrong

Tags: python

I am very confused on what exactly is going wrong and why the function is not being used.

```
text = input()
def replace_punctuation(text):
    ex_count = 0
    semi_count = 0
    new_text = " "
    print("Punctuation Replaced")
    print("exclamation_count:",int(ex_count))
    print("semicolon_count:",int(semi_count))          
    for punc in text:           # for loop call text
        if punc == "!":           # if & count for replace ! w/ .
            new_text += "."  
            ex_count +=1
        if punc == ";":
            new_text += ","
            semi_count += 0
        else:
            new_text += punc
    return text
```

Comment: "not being used"? Are you calling it? All you've shown here is the *definition* of the function.

Comment: You are returning `text` and not `new_text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get sure that you have run the function. A function itself is just a definition. You have to run the function:

```
text = input()
def replace_punctuation(text):
    ex_count = 0
    semi_count = 0
    new_text = " "
    print("Punctuation Replaced")
    print("exclamation_count:",int(ex_count))
    print("semicolon_count:",int(semi_count))          
    for punc in text:           # for loop call text
        if punc == "!":           # if & count for replace ! w/ .
            new_text += "."  
            ex_count +=1
        if punc == ";":
            new_text += ","
            semi_count += 0
        else:
            new_text += punc
    return text

replace_punctuation(text)
```

Second you have returned the wrong value. In your code you create the `new_text` variable and fill it with characters. So at the end you want to return that variable. So replace the last line with `return new_text`.

#### Another way

I read your code and I believe there is a better way to write it. You have some variables to count exclamation, punctuation and semicolon number of occurrence. And also you want to replace them as you have done in your code.

You can do this by this code:

```
def replace_punctuation(text):
    ex_count = text.count('!')
    semi_count = text.count(';')

    print("Punctuation Replaced")
    print("exclamation_count:", int(ex_count))
    print("semicolon_count:", int(semi_count)) 
             
    return text.replace('!', '.').replace(';', ',')
```

This way you count the number of occurrences with `.count()` method and not with a loop. And replace values with `.replace()` method.

If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful response. Completely slipped my mind to call the function

Comment: @joshclark234 Your welcome my friend. Please vote my answer as it helped you and accept it as the answer. Thank you. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are returning `text`, the function parameter, not `new_text`, the value you want. Second, you need to actually call the function to execute it, using `replace_punctuation(text)`. You can save it to a variable or print it, or whatever, but first you need to call it.